# How to get a specific data in java with Volley library?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am trying to check if user `ID` is equal to `CurrentUserID` and I use `for` loop. Although, I am using an `if` in order to check if ID == CurrentUserID but, when I run the code it ignores the if statement and it doesn't stop to the data I need and it continues the loop. Here is the code I wrote:

```
private void userInfo() {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, JSON_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject usersObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Name: "+usersObject, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    String ID = usersObject.getString("ID");
                    if (ID.equalsIgnoreCase(CurrentUser)) {
                        String fullName = usersObject.getString("fullName");
                        String userName = usersObject.getString("username");

                        fullname.setText(fullName);
                        username.setText(userName);
                    } else {
                        fullname.setText("No Name");
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Name: "+CurrentUser, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Name: "+ID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });


        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

However, If I don't use the for statement the code stops to `JSONObject usersObject = new JSONObject(response);` and it doesn't read the code bellow this line. What should I do to check the ID?

Comment: The for loop is totally redundant in your code. The IDE should have already pointed that to you (I assume you are using Android Studio).

Comment: But, when I don't use the for loop the code stops to `JSONObject usersObject = new JSONObject(response);` line and it doesn't read the if statement. It neither even reads the Toast after this line.

Comment: This is a good sign that you are receiving invalid JSON. To make sure this is the case check the stack trace.

Comment: @WaisKamal in Logcat I get this if I don't use for loop:`java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2021-12-07 18:16:35.601 24191-24191/com.example.app W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
2021-12-07 18:16:35.601 24191-24191/com.example.app W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)`

Comment: Try logging the `response` string and check if there is anything wrong with the JSON you are receiving.

Comment: How do I logging the `response`?

Comment: `Log.d("response", response)`

Comment: Maybe you got exception before the `if` condition and you think it ignores that. log the `catch` block to find out.

Comment: @WaisKamal There is no error with the JSON. When I am logging `response` is showing up correctly.

Comment: You need to step through your app with a debugger. It will help you identify the faulty line.

Comment: @AliBabadi I found the error. it throws `org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject` thank you very much.

Comment: @WaisKamal I found the error. I had to Log the catch. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @BradCruise so you have problem with your Json conversion

Comment: @AliBabadi Yes. I am gonna ask a new question because that is not relevant with the current question!

Comment: @BradCruise it would be great if you mark useful my answer